# How set path for local browser

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, configuration

I have this code

```
public static void init(){
    service = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File("src/test/resources/drivers/chromedriver.exe"))
            .usingAnyFreePort()
            .build();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(service);
    driver.get(URL);
}
```

and need set path `"src/test/resources/drivers/chromium/chrome.exe"`to start autotest.

How do it by Selenium?

Comment: Could you specify a question? What do exactly would you like to be done "by Selenium"? If you don't want to manage paths to driver executable there is a WebdriverManager service that will do it for you https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager

Comment: Did you tried System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver"); ?